# Inkscape "PDF + Latex" export

Tags: pdf, svg, latex, inkscape

I'm using inkscape to produce vector figures, save them in SVG format to export them later as "PDF + Latex" much in the vein of TUG inkscape+pdflatex guide.

Trying to produce a simple figure, however, turns out to be extremely frustating.

The first figure
[image]
is an example of the figure I would like to export in the form of "PDF + Latex" (shown here in PNG format).

If I export this to a PDF figure *without* latex macros the PDF produced looks exactly the same, except for some minor differences with the fonts used to render the text.

When I try to export this using the "PDF + Latex" option the PDF file produced consists on a PDF document of 2 pages (again as .png here):
[image]

This, of course, does not looks good when compiling my latex document. So far the guide at TUG has been very helpful, but I still can't produce a *working* "PDF + Latex" export from inkscape.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am having the same problem. I just upgraded to inkscape 0.91 and figures that previous exported correctly are now turned into 2-page PDFs. Any solutions?

Comment: This feature is no longer broken: https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/merge_requests/13 (this hint comes from https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/31788/vog )

Answer (score 7):

I worked around this by putting all the text in my drawing at the top

> select `text` and then `Object -> Raise to top`

*Inkscape* only generates the separate pages if the text is below another object.

Comment: Worked! I created another layer on top all layers and pushed all my text to that top most layer.

Answer (score 4):

I asked this question on the Inkscape online discussion page and got some very helpful guidance from one of the users there.

This is a known bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1417470 which was inadvertently introduced in Inkscape 0.91 in an attempt to fix a previous bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/771957.

It seems this bug does two things:

1. The *.pdf_tex file will have an extra `\includegraphics` statement which needs to be deleted manually as described in the link to the bug above.
2. The *.pdf file may be split into multiple pages, regardless of the size of the image. In my case the line objects were split off onto their own page. I worked around this by turning off the text objects (opacity to zero) and then doing a standard PDF export.

Comment: A patch was merged a week ago https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/merge_requests/13 hooray!

Comment: To avoid the bug on multiple pages, you can use the following commands in a shell script in which ${PDFFILE}_tex corresponds to the path of .pdf_tex file:
sed -i 's/\\\\/\n/g' ${PDFFILE}_tex; 
MAXPAGE=$(pdfinfo $PDFFILE | grep -oP "(?<=Pages:)\s*[0-9]+" | tr -d " "); 
sed -i "/page=$(($MAXPAGE+1))/,\${/page=/d}" ${PDFFILE}_tex;

Answer (score 3):

If you can execute linux commands, this works:

```
# Generate the .pdf and .pdf_tex files
inkscape -z -D --file="$SVGFILE" --export-pdf="$PDFFILE" --export-latex

# Fix the number of pages
sed -i 's/\\\\/\n/g' ${PDFFILE}_tex; 
MAXPAGE=$(pdfinfo $PDFFILE | grep -oP "(?<=Pages:)\s*[0-9]+" | tr -d " "); 
sed -i "/page=$(($MAXPAGE+1))/,\${/page=/d}" ${PDFFILE}_tex;
```

with:

- $SVGFILE: path of the svg
- $PDF_FILE: path of the pdf

It is possible to include these commands in a script and execute it automatically when compiling your tex file (so that you don't have to manually export from inkscape each time you modify your svg).

Answer (score 0):

Try it with an illustration that is less wide.

Alternatively, use a wider paperwidth setting.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and it has nothing to do with the paper width. The illustration is very small and fully within the paper. It is splitting the illustration into 2 parts - one for the arrows and one for the shapes. Suggestions?

Comment: yes, this turns out to be a version specific issue.