# Export `.pdf_tex` for Inkscape 1.0

Tags: svg, latex, inkscape

I would like to export from `.svg` to `.pdf_tex` from command line but on inkscape 1.0 or later, for instance, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41110512/9302545.

**Explanation**

In Inkscape 0.92 or earlier if I use a `.svg` file in a `.tex` I only use the `lualatex --shell-scape myfile.tex` and this compiler creates a folder `svg-inkscape` with a couple of files `name_svg_tex.pdf` and `name_svg-tex.pdf_tex`. Then I prefer to do it manually and generate the last two files for embeded svg in a pdf from `.tex`. In other words I want to replicate for Inkscape 0.92

```
inkscape -D --export-filename=MyOutput.pdf_tex spektralnorm.svg
```

These are the errors:

So

```
Did you run the export with Inkscape? There's no file
`./svg-inkscape/spektralnorm.pdf_tex'
although `./svg-inkscape/spektralnorm.pdf' was found.


inkscape:42353): Unknown option -z

Package svg Warning: The export with Inkscape failed for file
(svg)                `img/spektralnorm.svg'
(svg)                Troubleshooting: Please check in the log file how
(svg)                the invocation of Inkscape took place and try to
(svg)                execute it yourself in the terminal on input line 31.
```

The important is generate the file `.pdf_tex`, generate `.pdf` is covered.

```
inkscape -D --export-type="pdf" spektralnorm.svg
```

And thanks, I hope that [`svg` package](http://ctan.dcc.uchile.cl/info/svg-inkscape/InkscapePDFLaTeX.pdf) updates `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, `lualatex` for Inkscape 1.0

Please note that I can not do

```
 inkscape -D --export-filename=MyOutput.pdf_tex spektralnorm.svg
```

because only `InkFileExportCmd::export: Unknown export type: pdf_tex. Allowed values: [svg,png,ps,eps,pdf,emf,wmf,xaml]` are supported, not even as a `.tex`.

This [inkscape's docs](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Using_the_Command_Line) helps me create a `.pdf` from `.svg` but not a `.pdf_tex`.

Comment: What about 'inkscape -D --export-latex  --export-filename=my_file.pdf my_file.svg' ?

Comment: It's weird, for a single svg, exports 12 pages in the pdf. I tried with this [svg](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Matrix-2-norm_qtl1.svg) and is not similar to native exporting with \usepackage{svg} and lualatex --shell-escape foo.tex.

Comment: @Oromion The 12 pages get created because of the different layers of text and graphic elements. It will look fine in your document

Comment: Oh, thank you SamCarter. Then Moini answer is correct. I proposed this question because meanwhile I had TexLive 2019 with Inkscape 1.X I had an issue with lualatex when converts svg to pdf and generated .pdf_tex. But now I have TeXLive 2020 and works well as before.

Comment: off topic of this question, sorry for left TX.SX so I'm happy that will continue learning about LaTeX in new forums.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So then, I'm going to formalize my comment as an answer:

With Inkscape 1.0, the command should be:

```
inkscape -D --export-latex --export-filename=my_file.pdf my_file.svg
```

Comment: Where would I change the command in LaTeX? Some magic seems to call Inkscape and Inkscape does not recognize the command line parameters. Now I need to find out where the magic comes from.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, if someone does not want to name the exported file for some reason, this works for me:

```
inkscape -D --export-latex --export-type="pdf" my_file.svg
```